# multi user desktop application with privilege separaion

Tags: c++, postgresql

I am writing a C++ application with a postgresql 9.2 database backend. It is an accounting software. It is a muti user application with privilege separation features.

I need help in implementing the user account system. The privileges for users need not be mutually exclusive. Should I implement it at the application level, or at the database level?

The company is not very large at present. Assume about 15-20 offices with an average of 10 program users per office.

- Can I make use of the roles in postgres to implement this? Will it become too tedious, unmanageable or are there some flaws in such an approach?
- If I go via the application route, how do I store the set of privileges a user has? Will a binary string suffice? What if there are additional privileges later, how can I incorporate them? What do I need to do to ensure that there are no security issues? And in such an approach I am assuming the application connects with the privileges required for the most privileged user.
- Some combination of the two methods? Or something entirely different?

All suggestions and arguments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Never provide authorization from a client application, which is run on uncontrolled environment. And every device, that a user has physical access to, is an uncontrolled environment. This is security through obscurity — a user can simply use a debugger to get a database access credentials from client program memory and just use `psql` to do anything.

Use roles.

When I was developing an C++/PostgreSQL desktop application I've chosen to disallow all users access to modify all tables and I've created an API using Pl/PgSQL functions with `VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER` options. But I think it wasn't a best approach, as it's not natural and error prone to use for example:

```
select add_person(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

I think a better way would be to allow modifications to tables which a user needs to modify and, when needed, enforce authorization using BEFORE triggers, which would throw an error when current_user does not belong to a proper role.

But [remember to use `set search_path=...` option in all functions that have anything to do with security](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html#SQL-CREATEFUNCTION-SECURITY).

---

If you want to authorize read-only access to some tables then it gets even more complicated. Either you'd need to disable select privilege for these tables and create API using security definer functions for accessing all data. This would be a monster size API, extremely ugly and extremely fragile. Or you'd need to disable select privilege for these tables and create views for them using `create view with (security_barrier)`. Also not pretty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tometzky. I have a few questions: 1. What if users are not that technically oriented? And it is highly unlikely that they use the debugger approach?

Comment: 2. Another approach I can think of is, to use postgres roles. Use roles (no login rights) to define privileges on tabbles (like linux groups). Create a new role with login rights and required combination of privileges (implemented by inheriting the earlier group roles). Now, create a users tables that maps actual users to these postgres users (user roles). Naturailly, some users (admins/managers at the organization) would be granted privileges to create additional user roles, or group roles as they see fit.

Comment: Another question, can we not use another secure authentication method? I am not aware of all of them, neither well informed on how they work, but I believe (I have no research to support this) there must be another authentication method that can be used by the application to authenticate itself to the server, which cannot be duplicated by a malicious user. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Two points.  With PostgreSQL, you can have both user roles and kerberos 5 auth (or ssl cert auth for some things). Note that Kerberos auth can be allowed transitively so a user can log into a web app with a kerberos ticket and the web app can take that ticket and then log into the db with it.  This is the direction I would go, but it is suppemental to getting db security right in the first place.

Comment: Second pioint, yes, use roles (inherit nologin) like groups.  You can automate this through the use of stored procedures and application logic if you must.  This is how we do things in LedgerSMB.